# Angular set APP_BASE_HREF from LOCALE_ID

Tags: angular, routes, internationalization

I'm internationalizing my application right now. Since I use routing in the application I have to set the APP_BASE_HREF in the routing-module.ts.

```
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/fr' }
  ]
```

How can I set the value dynamically, depending on the current language?

Here's what I've been trying to do. But this was not successful.

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' + LOCALE_ID}
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above (in your second example) simply uses the injection token LOCALE_ID itself. What you want is to obtain the value of the token. You can do that by using a factory:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useFactory: (locale: string) => locale,
    deps: [LOCALE_ID]
  },
]
```